# SSRS 2005 - Subscription Email is squished to the left

Tags: email, reporting-services, outlook, reporting, reportingservices-2005

I have a data driven subscription that uses web archive as the format to embed the report in an e-mail message.

My problem is that the report is smashed over to the left in a thin band, approximately 150 - 200 pixels wide (my guess).

When I open it in outlook it is smashed.  I can click to view it in a browser, which opens it in IE.  In IE, it looks fine.

How do I get the report to expand horizontally to fit in my e-mail?

Here's a few settings that might be necessary to figure this out, but I'm not sure if they have anything to do with the issue I'm seeing.

1. Size is set to 8.5in wide by 4in high
2. Margin is set to 1in, 1in, 1in, 1in
3. Interactive size is 8.5in by 11in

**EDIT:**

Interestingly, when I turn on the ruler in Outlook, the slider is set and will not move from the width of the smashed report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a hack, I've created a 1 px tall, 8.5 inch wide white image and embedded it in my report. This forces the report to 8.5 inches wide, but doesn't explain how to get the rendering engine to make the report expand automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the email extension for SSRS?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160334.aspx

Comment: That is exactly what I'm using.

Comment: But it does not address the formatting issues.  That only addresses how to send a report through e-mail.

Comment: are you using the std setup for the SMTP server and allowed host names? I am trying to replicate the issue on my side.

Comment: what report regions/widgets are you using in the report: tables, matrix, list, maps, etc.? When I send a table to Outlook 2010 using SSRS in SQL Server 08 R2, I cannot replicate your issue.

Comment: There is no table, because the report is just text boxes and an image.  Since my datasets (three of them for all the data) only return 1 row, any time I inject data into my text I do something like `First(Fields!FirstName.Value, "UserDataSet")`

Answer (score 0):

We faced a similar problem and after a lot of workarounds we finally found out the one parameter in SSRS configuration that did the trick: **OutlookCompat**. With this enabled the HTML4.0 e-mails no longer look squished in Outlook.

See the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155395%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for more details. You can set this value either in the SSRS configuration file (for all reports and callers) or directly when calling the ASMX.

Example of the SSRS configuration:

```
<Extension Name="HTML4.0" Type="...">
    <Configuration>
       <DeviceInfo>
          <OutlookCompat>True</OutlookCompat>
       </DeviceInfo>
    </Configuration>
</Extension>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using outlook 2007 to view the report, this problem has a hotfix.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/935399